# How does Node.js support Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to Node.js and Express.js; using the Express.js executable (express) to generate an express application, I'm given the following lines in app.js:

```
...
var app = express();
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    ...
});
...
```

I'm wondering how node's createServer function can accept an express app? Does Node.js natively support Express.js?

Comment: It might help you to think about Express as a framework only and forget about the Express executable that you used to create the skeleton of your project since that's probably the last time you'll use the executable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Node's [`http.createServer`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener) method only requires that the parameter passed to it (`app` in this case) be callable as a function that it will call on the `'request'` event.  So Express just needs to satisfy that basic requirement to integrate with the node.js http server.

Answer (score 2):

`app` is just any other object. Node is not natively supporting Express. Express is just emulating the correct parameter for `http.createServer()`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `Node.js` doesnt natively support Express. Express is just a web-framework built on top of `Node.js`

Comment: and what is sinatra to ruby...? Don't repeat what all the questions here in stackoverflow say to explain what is express. Please.